# How to read complete "grep" manual?

Tags: grep, man

I wanted to read about the `--include` feature by doing `man grep`. But that section is not found. I found the information on a webpage instead [GNU Grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

Is there any other command to see the `grep` documentation that has information on the `--include` feature?

Comment: try `info grep` instead of `man grep`

Comment: `--include` is mentioned in [the ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/grep.1.html).

Comment: Which distribution are you using, and how up-to-date?  Is it definitely GNU grep that is installed?  That option is documented in the upstream sources for the man page: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/doc/grep.in.1#n538

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most GNU software is fully documented in `info` manuals rather than traditional manual pages. To access this, use `info`:

```
info grep
```

You can then navigate in the documentation. This is mentioned at the end of [`grep(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html):

> **Full Documentation**
>
> A [complete manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/) is available.  If  the  info  and  grep  programs  are
>          properly installed at your site, the command
>
> ```
> info grep
> ```
>
> should give you access to the complete manual.

(The current `grep` manpage does mention `--include` though, albeit briefly.)

Comment: And in `info grep`, type `i` to bring the index, type `--inc<Tab><Return>` to jump to the definition of `--include`.